# Migration from toplink/eclipselink equalOuterJoin to Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipselink, hibernate-criteria, toplink

I am migrating really old application from toplink to the Hibernate.
An i have the folowing code:

```
ExpressionBuilder expHVLMAVI  ...

expHVLMAVI.anyOfAllowingNone(perf2CollectionString).get("bereichsCode")
.equalOuterJoin(bereichsCode)
```

Any ideas how to migrate it to the Hibernate Criteria API? I am no idea what happens in this line (Any explanation will be appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

expHVLMAVI  likely represents a class/entity in your model, so anyOfAllowingNone is an outerjoin over the perf2CollectionString relationship, and then a join over the bereichsCode relationship.  This is just part of an expression to be used in the rest of the query.

In JPQL, this would be equavlent to something like:

```
"Select... from ExpHVLMAVI expHVLMAVI left outer join expHVLMAVI.perf2CollectionString as perf2CollectionString join perf2CollectionString.bereichsCode as bereichsCode"
```

What you do with the bereichsCode declaration is then up to you.

Comment: Thank you, in JPQL it looks much more readable than in eclipselink API